# Silverlight: Type 'X' was not found because 'Y' is an unknown namespace

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a SilverLight project in which I want a textbox to have a placeholder(watermark).
To do this, I have created a new Behavior by looking at [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/silverlight-watermark-textbox-behavior).

The namespace in which the class is defined:

```
namespace SignificantDigits.MediWatch.ReceptionistApp.SL
{
    public class Watermark : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        //Members
    }
}
```

In my silverlight control (XAML), I have used this behavior:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:SignificantDigits.MediWatch.ReceptionistApp.SL"
        Width="950" Name="OpdRowStackPanel" Background="Transparent" Height="55" >
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="737*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="213*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock Name="SerialNoTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,15,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1." VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource CustomLabel}"/>
<TextBox Name="MedicineName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="41,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxStyle}">

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors> //Behaviour used here
        <sl:Watermark Text="Medicine Name" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

</TextBox>
```

This compiles without any errors. But when I run this, the following exception is thrown -

> The type 'Watermark' was not found because
>   'clr-namespace:SignificantDigits.MediWatch.ReceptionistApp.SL' is an
>   unknown namespace. [Line: 13 Position: 59]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by mentioning the **assembly name** along with the namespace name in the XAML.

```
xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:SignificantDigits.MediWatch.ReceptionistApp.SL;assembly=SignificantDigits.MediWatch.ReceptionistApp.SL"
```